# I don't understand this Rust closure syntax

Tags: rust

I am currently reading the source code of [dua-cli](https://github.com/Byron/dua-cli) and came across a function call that requires an argument satisfying the Fn trait. The code is:

```rust
type WalkDir = jwalk::WalkDirGeneric<((), Option<Result<std::fs::Metadata, jwalk::Error>>)>;
impl WalkOptions {
    pub(crate) fn iter_from_path(&self, root: &Path, root_device_id: u64) -> WalkDir {
        WalkDir::new(root)
            .follow_links(false)
            .sort(match self.sorting {
                TraversalSorting::None => false,
                TraversalSorting::AlphabeticalByFileName => true,
            })
            .skip_hidden(false)
            .process_read_dir({
            // I don't understand the following two lines
                let ignore_dirs = self.ignore_dirs.clone();
                let cross_filesystems = self.cross_filesystems;
                move |_, _, _, dir_entry_results| { 
                  // Closure logic here
                }
            })
      }
}
```

The process_read_dir function signature is

```rust
pub fn process_read_dir<F>(self, process_by: F) -> Selfwhere
    F: Fn(Option<usize>, &Path, &mut C::ReadDirState, &mut Vec<Result<DirEntry<C>>>) + Send + Sync + 'static,
```

In the above code, the function call doesn't **directly** pass a closure to process_read_dir. Instead, it begins with the declaration of two local variables enclosed in curly braces, followed by a closure `move |_, _, _, dir_entry_results|`. I'm wondering why this code is considered valid for the function call. I mean if it only pass the closure as argument, I am fine, but I am confused with the local variable declaration in the front and the outside curly braces.

Could you please explain?

Answer (score 9):

```rust
{
    let ignore_dirs = self.ignore_dirs.clone();
    let cross_filesystems = self.cross_filesystems;
    move |_, _, _, dir_entry_results| { 
        // Closure logic here
    }
}
```

is just a regular [block expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html), like all blocks in Rust it evaluates to the last expression in it in this case the closure.

The two assignments are simply assignments, they do what all `let` bindings do, not sure where you're confused there either.